# android:onclick="" - to call a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I'm wondering if it would be possible, to use the XML-onclick attribtue to call another XML-"`View`".

Means if I'm in a menu and click on the button "Create new Drawing", shouldn't I be able to call just another XML-View to bring up more options?

What I know is: `android:onclick="hellothere"` calls the method `public void hellothere(View view)` in the `Activity` to whom the view belongs, but why does it has to be used with code, instead that I'd just call another XML-Layout?

Example: `andorid:onclick="new_page"` (`new_page.xml opens`)

Comment: Nice but it is not possible !!!

Comment: but what purpose should it serve? What does *new_page.xml opens* mean?

Comment: You cannot "call a layout". You need to attach this layout somewhere. Either to existing `Activity` or to the new `Activity` or to a `Dialog`.

Comment: Never heard of seperating logic from ui? ;)

Comment: @blackbelt I thougt you may be able to create a complete GUI and after that linking the parts to the logic. At the moment it seems to be like the logic is merged in the same file as the UI. From what I've learned, this is a bad idea, if I got that right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling another xml without a context is not possible in android. The context would be something like an activity, fragment etc.
If you want to inflate another xml into an area on your desired layout without activity transition, use fragments instead.

Heres's a simple code how to attach a fragment in a specific or generic area:

**attaching to generic fragment area:**

```
    FragmentTransaction ft;

    Fragment mFragment = new MySampleFragment();
    ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(android.R.id.content, mFragment, "samplefragment");
    ft.commit();
```

as you can see above, we attach the Fragment into the default fragment inflater of android which is **"android.R.id.content"**.It gives you the root element of a view, without having to know its actual name/type/ID. Check out Get root view from current activity

**attaching to specific fragment area:**

```
        FragmentTransaction ft;

        Fragment mFragment = new MySampleFragment();
        currentFragment = mFragment;
        ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        ft.replace(R.id.myfragmentid, mFragment, "samplefragment");

        ft.commit();
```

Here we inflated the fragment inside a specific area with an actual ID which is **R.id.myfragmentid**. In this case you can specify which area in your page you will show your desired output upon a specific events like button click, hover, etc.

Hope it helps. Cheers! :)

Comment: Hi Dude, thanks for your answer. For me, the first part was important. I cannot really follow your code, but that doesn't matter. I know how to call another view in the MainActivity but I hoped, it would be possible to switch the layouts without using code (would look more clean to me).

Comment: :) Im glad it helped you somehow. The codes are just ways how to attached your fragment in a view. Anyways the android docs for fragments explains better.